# Is it wrong to put semicolon after braces of if block?

Tags: c++

I use MSVC++ 2008 and 2010 and i am a little confused about auto formatting. When i write code like this :

```
if(true)
    if(true)
    {
    }

    if(true)
    {
    }
```

and then i push CTRL+F but nothing happens and last condition stays in place but it should be aligned on a level with first condition. Behavior changes to right way if i add semicolon after braces of second condition like that :

```
if(true)
    if(true)
    {
    };

if(true)
{
}
```

So the question is, is it right to add semicolon after condition according to C++ standard or it's just incorrect behavior of MSVC++?

Comment: Putting semicolons is transparent, unless required from the syntax.

Comment: It's not required, Visual Studio is just a special needs IDE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That semicolon is completely superfluous.  Looks like you've found a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the editor as opposed to in the compiler.